# How can I block keyboard and mouse input in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, keyboard, mouse

I'm looking for some code (preferably C#) that will prevent keyboard and mouse input.

Comment: Can you give some more context as to why you would want to do this?

Comment: Do you mean only in your application or globally across the system?

Comment: And to what; after all, you could be referring to a textbox, which setting the readonly property would do it.

Comment: Sorry I wish to block input globally

Answer (score 23):

Expanding on Josh's (correct) answer.  Here's the PInvoke signature for that method.

```
public partial class NativeMethods {

    /// Return Type: BOOL->int
    ///fBlockIt: BOOL->int
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", EntryPoint="BlockInput")]
    [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern  bool BlockInput([System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fBlockIt) ;

}

public static void BlockInput(TimeSpan span) {
  try { 
    NativeMethods.BlockInput(true);
    Thread.Sleep(span);
  } finally {
    NativeMethods.BlockInput(false);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Added some code to demonstrate how to block for an interval

Comment: Many thanks for this. Do you have any code which uses this signature? For example block input, wait for 30 seconds, re-enable input.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the Managed Windows API, it might have something that wraps this functionality already.
http://mwinapi.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Matt, i usually just grab the sig from the PInvoke Interop Assistant http://www.codeplex.com/clrinterop

Comment: @JaredPar I didn't work in my application! does it work on win 7?

Comment: I gave this a shot and it did not work. Does it require privilege elevation?

Comment: It does require privileges for obvious reasons (you're blocking most input from the user - control-alt-del and maybe a few others will still work)

Comment: This worked for me but I wanted to disable only Keyboard and mouse and support touch. BlockInput blocks everything. Does this accepts any parameter for type of input?

Comment: Can someone explain how to make this work at all? It doesn't block anything for me but apparently works for others.

Comment: @Zed it also doesn't work for me, but if I run the app with Administrator rights - it works fine. It can be disabled by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del.   https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.blockinput

Answer (score 7):

Look into the [BlockInput](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646290.aspx) Win32 function

Sounds like some fun testing :)

Comment: Can I have only specific type of inputs to be blocked? Like only keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public partial class NativeMethods
{        
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "BlockInput")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool BlockInput([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fBlockIt);
}
```

`internal` is not `public`. So it does not fall into the CA1401

A public or protected method in a public type has the [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/code-quality/ca1401-p-invokes-should-not-be-visible?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN) attribute