# Disable keyboard in windows form asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I need to disable all keys from windows form .is there any way to disable keyboard on windows form in C#

Comment: it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586547/how-can-i-block-keyboard-and-mouse-input-in-c

Comment: I want to diasable inputs only on a form not globaly

Comment: This seems like it might not be the right solution to your problem. Would it not be better to simply disable anything that might be affected *by* said keys?

Comment: @matthew Haugen   I  need to disable only  keys.In my scenario mouse needs to be work properly only needs to disable keyboard on a particular  form

Comment: What functionalities are you hoping to hinder? There's probably a generic solution, but I'm looking to hone in your question a bit. I take it you don't want tab stops working, but is there anything else?

Comment: @matthew Haugen Can you Provide me a sample c# code for disable keyboard  in windows forms